# Determining the amplitude for a specific cycle (frequency) using a fast fourier transform

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have been set an assignment using a dataset obtained from remote sensing on sea surface height anomaly. Before starting the question I'm having trouble with, I have loaded the data into matlab, filtered it so that it only contains data within the desired geographic location and plotted the data as a function of time.

The question I'm struggling with specifically is:

"Determine the amplitude of the annual cycle in the SSHA data at 36°, 21°W
using fast Fourier transform."

where SSHA is the sea surface height anomaly data.

As I said above, I have filtered the data. I have also used the fast fourier transform command on the filtered data; fft(sshaFiltered)

and plotted the absolute data; abs(sshaFilteredFft); plot(sshaFilteredAbs).

This has enabled me to plot the data as a function of it's frequency (I believe). I just don't understand how to determine the amplitude of it's annual cycle.

Any response is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What is the sampling frequency of input data? Is it like one per day?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I have information that says it was collected over 10 years and cycles 1-350. I'm not sure if that means 350 cycles in total or between 1 and 350 cycles per year? When I make the fft abs plot, I have 1-350 appear on the x-axis with the ssha on the y-axis. If this helps, I have another data set of to use for later questions which is over five years with 183-350 cycles.

Comment: Depending on how you plotted the data that 350 in x-axis could mean you had 350 samples. You need to know sampling frequency to determine what is the cycle of each point in fft. Otherwise you would not know which point in fft corresponds to annual cycle.